# assign index to array of buttons?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, button, javafx

I created a Matrix of Button in JavaFX with a for loop and arrays.
Now I would like to assign a value to the Buttons.

Here is my code:

```
int SIZE = 10;
int length = SIZE;
int width = SIZE;

GridPane root = new GridPane();

matrix = new Button[width][length]; 
matrix[0][0] = 1;


for(int y = 0; y < length; y++)
{
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();


            int rand1 = rand.nextInt(2);
            matrix[x][y] = new Button(/*"(" + rand1 + ")"*/); 
            matrix[x][y].setText("(" + rand1 + ")");   
            matrix[x][y].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Random Binary Matrix (JavaFX)");
                }
            });

            root.add(matrix[x][y], y, x);
        }
}
```

Eclipse Error at this part :
matrix[0][0] = 1;

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Of course you cannot assign `int` to type `Button`. That's why `matrix[x][y] = new Button();` works but `matrix[0][0] = 1;` doesn't. What are you trying to achieve with this anyways?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to develop a game, that includes a matrix of buttons. In the first step a row of buttons is getting invisible and in the second step the matrix is rebuilding with all buttons and the user has to click the exact route in the matrix.

Comment: @Mike I think the question in the previous comment was: what are you trying to achieve with the code `matrix[0][0]=1`? That code makes no sense (you can't assign `1` to a `Button`). What are you expecting that to actually do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lists, i think is more adapted :

```
// 1 dimension
List<Button> btns = new ArrayList<>(10); 
// 2 dimensions                  
List<List<Button>> btns = new ArrayList<>(10);
btns.get(0).get(0).setText("Hi");
```

I didn't try it :

```
for(List list: btns){

  for(Button btn: (List<Button>) list){

      //Edit for each button !

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have never worked with arrayList before. How can I realize the ArrayList in the for loops?